# Total Commander How to feed list listbox with selected files

Tags: total-commander

Just like Search result can feed the listbox (which opens new temporary tab),
is there a way to:

1. simply select files from one directory and feed the listbox?
2. select files from multiple directories and feed the same listbox?

Just to rename listbox's temporary tab and you could have favorite list of items over which you could perform more actions. This would increase productivity tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding #1:**

After you select the files activate:

`Menu > Show > Only Selected Files`

**Regarding #2:**

It's probably not what you were after, but you can use DiskDir / DiskDir Extended to add files (using a packer functionality, so you create an 'archive' file with extension `.lst` which contains a hierarchical list of the added files. You can then change source folder and then add more files. Later you just click on the `.lst` file and it looks no different then your normal file / folder list. Unfortunatelly you **cannot** rename the files, but you can **launch** them, with an extra confirmation.

**UPDATE**

Similar functionalitybut with 'source' renaming functionality limited to one file only (?): `Virtual Panel`, (File System Plugin, accessible through the `Network Neighborhood` 'drive'). It can launch files without a confirmation window. **Rename** 'source/target' file when you use it's own subbar (located here: `%%COMMANDER_PATH%%\Plugins\WFX\VirtualPanel\EN\VirtualPanel.bar`, make sure that you also have installed the `AskParam` addon and have paths in the VirtualPanel.bar right (both to AskParam.exe and VPBatch.exe). 'Regular' rename will change the file name only in the virtual panel.

URL: [Virtual Panel Plugin](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=24293)